# Does adding too many entries to the hosts file causes internet slow down?

Tags: networking, performance, hosts-file

I just wanted to clarify one thing, Does adding too many entries to the %windir%/system32/drivers/etc/hosts causes internet slow down?

Does duplicate hosts entry slows down browsing performance?

What will happen if I delete the hosts file, will it speedup browsing speed?

I'm using windows 10

Comment: Not definitive but... it can, it might, probably not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.The hosts entry would be written to DNS cache.It makes Name resolution faster.

You could delete or reset the hosts file to prove it.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/972034/how-to-reset-the-hosts-file-back-to-the-default